# None of my friends live near me. vs None of us speaks Italian

Tags: pronouns

As I see from my grammar book both sentences are correct, but I don't understand why in first one is "live", but in second - "speaks"? Could you explain this difference?

> None of my friends live near me.
>
> None of us speaks Italian.

TIA

Comment: Well, I was taught that _none_ takes a singular verb because it means _not one_, but I suppose I shall be told that that is being pedantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to another answer, idiomatic use sometimes overrules normally assumed syntactic rules.

While *none* normally does take a singular verb, there are some specific formations (such as *none of my friends **live** near me*), where people simply use the plural verb against prescriptive grammar rules.

In point of fact, it's not as clear cut as the question suggests. While some people do say *none of my friends **live** near me*, other people say *none of my friends **lives** near me*.

Shortening the phrase to just *none of them* ***live*** versus *none of them* ***lives***, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none%20of%20them%20live%2Cnone%20of%20them%20lives&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20live%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20lives%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20live%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20lives%3B%2Cc0) indicates that both variations exist in print. The plural verb is actually twice as common, but the singular form still has its use:

[image: none of them live versus none of them lives]

From the perspective of the common association of words, I think it makes more sense for people to think of *friends* (plural) with *live* (plural), despite the fact that *none* would normally entail *lives* (singular).

If I were to write the phrase myself, I would, recognizing that both are acceptable in general, use *lives* since that's what's more technically warranted. But I would not say that somebody using the other version was wrong in their use.

---

Incidentally, the same analysis can be done with the second sentence. With respect to Google Ngram Viewer, I have shortened this comparison between *none of them* ***speak*** and *none of them* ***speaks***. As with the first sentence, the [plural version is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none+of+them+speak%2Cnone+of+them+speaks&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20speak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20speaks%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20speak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20them%20speaks%3B%2Cc0)—however, in this case, the difference is so small that the two have effectively the same degree of use:

[image: none of them speak versus none of them speaks]

---

Finally, consider how changing *none* to *not one* (as suggested in a comment under the question) would make a dramatic change to how the sentences sound:

> ✔ None of my friends live near me.
>   ✔ None of my friends lives near me.

*but*

> ？ *Not* ***one*** of my friends live near me.
>   ✔ *Not* ***one*** of my friends lives near me.

By replacing the words used at the start of the sentence, what sounds okay with *none* suddenly sounds very strange (if not unacceptable) with *not one*, primarily, I think, because of the use of ***one*** in the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

In formal spoken and written styles, we use **none of** with a singular verb when it is the subject. However, some dictionaries recognise that, in informal styles, people often use plural verbs:

> None of that surprises me.
>
> Indeed, none of his novels is well shaped or well written.
>
> None of the products have been tested on animals and all the bottles
>   are recyclable. (informal)

[No, none, and none of (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/no-none-and-none-of)